# Why is Alert only presented in SwiftUI when unwrapped before?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mvvm

**Context**

I am using the `SPIndicator` library to present Apple like notifications. However, I tested two different approaches, one is working, one is not. The first one produces the Alerts as expected while the second one just does not show any Alert at all.

Since both are basically the same with the exception of the Alert being Optional in the first one, I am not sure what causes this different behaviour.

I do know that the library is very specific, however, I guess the problem must be in my Swift Code itself, since the Library's Modifier gets the same parameters both times.

---

**Code**

```swift
ContentView()
    .modifier(AlertViewModifier())

// Now, you can raise an Alert from everywhere in the App.
AlertViewModel.shared.present(Alert(...))
```

- Variant A: This does work

```swift
public class AlertViewModel: ObservableObject {
    public static let shared = ViewModel()
    
    @Published var show: Bool = false
    @Published private(set) var alert: Alert?
    
    public func present(_ alert: Alert) {
        self.alert = alert
        self.show = true
    }
}

public struct AlertViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    @ObservedObject private var alertVM = AlertViewModel.shared
    
    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if let safeAlert = alertVM.alert {
            content
                .SPIndicator(isPresent: $alertVM.show, title: safeAlert.title)
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}
```

- Variant B: This does not work

```swift
public class AlertViewModel: ObservableObject {
    public static let shared = ViewModel()
    
    @Published var show: Bool = false
    @Published private(set) var alert = Alert(...)
    
    public func present(_ alert: Alert) {
        self.alert = alert
        self.show = true
    }
}

public struct AlertViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    @ObservedObject private var alertVM = AlertViewModel.shared
    
    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .SPIndicator(isPresent: $alertVM.show, title: alertVM.alert.title)
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

- Why is the second approach not working? Since the first one is redrawing the entire content on the first Alert presentation, the second one would be the cleaner solution.

Comment: I'm not sure why with this specific library it doesn't work, but you may want to check out "Demystifying SwiftUI" from WWDC for info on why the first approach may not be a good idea in general (spoiler: it breaks identify)

Comment: `ObservableObject` for model data not view data.

Comment: @malhal what do you mean by that? The ViewModel (ObservableObject) contains Model Data with `Alert`.